# java.lang.NullPointerException: when using another class of the same package without package declaration

Tags: java, package

I have a package `test` and inside this package i have two class files.

1. Const.java
2. Test.java

**Const.java**

```java
//package test;
class Event{
    final String NEW_ORDER = "NEW_ORDER";
}
public class Const{
    final static String PENDING = "PENDING";
    final static String IN_PROGRESS = "IN_PROGRESS";
    final static String COMPLETED = "COMPLETED";
    final static Event ORDER = new Event();
}
```

**Test.java**

```java
package test;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Const.COMPLETED);
        System.out.println(Const.IN_PROGRESS);
        System.out.println(Const.PENDING);
        System.out.println(Const.ORDER.NEW_ORDER);
    }
}
```

When running i am getting this output.

```js
// output
COMPLETED
IN_PROGRESS
PENDING
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.getClass()" because "test.Const.ORDER" is null
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

#### uncomment `package test;` in **Const.java**

When i do this every thing is working fine and output

```
COMPLETED
IN_PROGRESS
PENDING
NEW_ORDER
```

#### Comment `System.out.println(Const.ORDER.NEW_ORDER);` in Test.java

When i comment this line in `Test.java` and keep `package test;` commented then there is no error

```java
COMPLETED
IN_PROGRESS
PENDING
```

#### Question

When `Const.java` doesn't has any package declared then how `Test.java` is accessing `Const` class inside `Test` class?

If `Const.IN_PROGRESS` is accessed by `Test.java` if package is not declared in `Const.java` then why accessing this `Const.ORDER.NEW_ORDER` is an error?

Both are related question, so i didn't asked separately.

Comment: "When i comment this line" That's not what would happen with this code. The package is essentially irrelevant, other than you'd need to add import statements. Please can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If you're using a modern IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse, it should be obvious how to remedy the problem (and in fact there should be suggestions available).  Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am using eclipse- Suggestions are available, but i am exploring this things.

Comment: @AndyTurner `The package is essentially irrelevant` you are right. But  i would like to  explore the things and what would happen if we have a class inside a package, which has  `package`  unspecified. Also, the error is occuring when i am invoking `Const.ORDER.NEW_ORDER`

Comment: The error (classname = *Test1*) does not correspond to the code in the question (classname = *Test*). Since you are assigning `final static Event ORDER = new Event()`, it cannot be `null` later. Thus, the NPE cannot happen if the code compiles (depending on packages / imports).

Comment: @Matt Typing mistake, now i fixed the question. Actually i was having `Test1.java` on my system, but while writing on `stackoverflow.com` i write it `Test.java` for simplicity.

Comment: @Matt can you explain me this line `Since you are assigning final static Event ORDER = new Event(), it cannot be null later` `final static Event ORDER`  has a reference to `Event` instance.  if  `Const.PENDING` can be accessed then why `Const.ORDER.NEW_ORDER` can not be accesssed.

Comment: `ORDER` is a static field, so a new event is assigned to it when the class is initialised. Additionally, it is a final field which means that it cannot be set to `null` later. In consequence, the NPE can never happen with the code in the question when other fields of `Const` can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks, i  understood.